# Docker could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool

Tags: debian, networking, docker

I'm using Docksal for CI with Jenkins. Docksal is docker-compose client, and for every git branch I have, there is separate docker-compose network.

Problem is that I got following error when try to run more than 28 docker networks.

> could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among
>   the defaults to assign to the network

Is there any way to "hack" docker and create more than 28(29) docker networks?

I'm using Debian 8, with 4.9.0 kernel and docker 17.04.ce